# Python - How to print out all letters from a list

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

There are given lots and I'm suppose to print out all letters, either uppercase or lower case. I'm also not allowed to use any built in functions. I'm having difficult printing out the list of letters. All i get in return is an empty closed bracket.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

alphabet2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def get_symbols(lot):
list = []
for i in lot:
    if (i == alphabet or i == alphabet2):
        list.append(lot);
return list
```

The given lot:

```
lot1 = [['.', '.', 'a', 'D', 'D'],
       ['.', '.', 'a', '.', '.'],
       ['A', 'A', '.', 'z', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', 'z', '.'],
       ['.', '.', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```

My output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tester4p.py", line 233, in test_get_symbols_2
def test_get_symbols_2 (self): self.assertEqual (get_symbols(lot1()),['a','D','A','z','C'])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ['a', 'D', 'A', 'z', 'C']

Second list contains 5 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
'a'

- []
+ ['a', 'D', 'A', 'z', 'C']
```

Expected Output:

```
['a', 'D', 'A', 'z', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way that does not involve nested loops, but this is what I would do:

```
alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def get_symbols(lot):
    lst = []
    for chars in lot:
        for c in chars:
            if c in alphabets and c not in lst:
                lst.append(c)
    return lst
```

A few things to note:

- You should avoid using variable names that Python uses like `list`.
- `i == alphabet` will only be `True` if `i` is the string `'abc...'`, but `i in alphabet` will be `True` if `i` is any character in the string `'abc...'`

## Update:

Try this variant to avoid the nested loops:

```
alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def get_symbols(lot):
    flat_lot = [item for sublist in lot for item in sublist]
    lst = []
    for c in flat_lot:
        if c in alphabets and c not in lst:
            lst.append(c)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the lot1 and then filter out the alphabets

```
lot1 = [['.', '.', 'a', 'D', 'D'],
       ['.', '.', 'a', '.', '.'],
       ['A', 'A', '.', 'z', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', 'z', '.'],
       ['.', '.', 'C', 'C', 'C']]

import operator
lot1 = reduce(operator.concat, lot1)
lot1 = filter(str.isalpha, lot1)
lot1 = list(set(lot1))
lot1.sort()
print lot1
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C', 'D', 'a', 'z']
```